How to avoid these errors regarding android folder in flutter app
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugUnitTestSources'.

this and base files have different roots:
D:\flutter-projects\new_proj\build\path_provider_android 

and
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.14\android.

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.2-all.zip'.
The specified initialization script 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.36.0\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\58\0.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle' does not exist.
after connecting with fire base my android folder started to display this error....I tried with several java versions there but it did not fix...what can i do to solve this problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
